# Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^xf(t)\,dt=a$ if $f$ is continuous and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=a$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Suppose $f$ is continuous and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = a$. Prove that $$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{x} \int_{0}^x f(t) dt = a.$$

I don't see why in the solution below they take the integral from $1$ to $N$ instead of $0$ to $N$ and how that proves the result. Also is $M$ considered to be positive?

**Book solution:**

[image]

Comment: Probably a typo. There's at least one other typo I see: "Then for $N>0$"can't be right, because $N$ is already fixed - you look at what follows and decide that was supposed to be "Then for $M>0$"

Answer (score 1):

This can be done a LOT quicker using L'Hospital's Rule:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{x} \int_{0}^x f(t) dt = 
\lim_{x \to \infty}{\displaystyle \int_{0}^x f(t) dt \over x} =
\lim_{x\to\infty} {f(x) \over 1} = a.
$$
(After all, if $f$ is continuous, then $\displaystyle{d\over dx} \int_k^x f(t)\,dt = f(x)$, for any constant $k$.)

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: Nice, thanks for this. But as for the original proof, do you know why their proof works?

Comment: It's all epsilons and deltas.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman Thanks for the title of my next paper.

Comment: For the book proof, you can replace continuity with something much weaker.

Comment: Yeah, continuity doesn't seem necessary for this statement to work. It's really just there so the integral exists